# Do-while equivalent in Expect

Tags: expect

Is there any instruction in "Expect" Scripting which performs a do-while operation?
If so please share the details

Comment: @Tamin -  Expect is an extension to TCL- you might want to consider researching TCL itself.

Answer (score -1):

Expect is an extension of TCL. TCL defines the [while-loop](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm). The [TCL syntax](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/Tcl.html) is a little different than other languages, so you'll need to make sure your conditional evaluates properly--but conceptually, loops are loops, regardless of the language.